# System.Array.CopyTo() and System.Array.Clone()?

Tags: .net, arrays

I know that `CopyTo` requires to have a destination array while `Clone` returns a new array. but i have read that both perform shallow copy and refer same instance..

So if I have

```
A = [1,2,3,4]
```

and I `Clone` it and get

```
B = [1,2,3,4].
```

Now, if I change

```
B[0] = 9.
```

This means that A will now be

```
A = [9,2,3,4].
```

Is that correct? And is this correct for `CopytTo()`?

Comment: why don't you try it? it will take less time to try than to wait for an answer.

Comment: Did you try it?  If you have Visual Studio handy, you could write a short code snippet and get your answer in a couple of minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you do `B[0] = 9` you are replacing element with 0 index in `B` array, so `A` array will stay the same (you don't change it actually) and it doesn't matter which method (`CopyTo` or `Clone`) you are using (since `A` doesn't reference to `B`).

Comment: so if I change A array than accordingly B will be changed or not?

Comment: If you `Clone` or `CopyTo`, then B will not be changed since they are referencing two different memory addresses.

Answer (score 1):

No. `Clone` typically creates a new instance and copy whatever in the original object to it. Other words, A and B are pointing at two different memories. In your case, A will remain the intact.

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
```

A will only be changed if we set

```
B = A;
```

In this case, both A and B are pointing at the same address.

However, if we set

```
B = A.Clone();
```

Then whatever changes made to B will not affect A. `CopyTo` also does the same process as `Clone` except that it lets you specify the position in A to start copying data to B.

Answer (score 0):

The MSDN documentation of `Array.Clone` specifically goes through this example to show that no it will not change both copies.

This makes sense, as the array object will be a series of memory addresses pointing to the object. When you clone the array, you create a copy of the memory addresses. If you change one of the arrays, you change the value of the memory address. Hence the change will be comfined to that array.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.array.clone(v=vs.110).aspx